# Getting [Object object] and incorrect updates from attribute change event in <lightning:input />

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-bug

I am trying to leverage the new (as of Winter '17) `<lightning:input />` field to take advantage of the built-in field validation. However, if I am using several `<lightning:input />` tags in a component and those inputs are displaying fields from an object, changing the top level object with `component.set('v.myObj', newObj);` results in all input values being replaced with `[Object object]`. If I instead update a specific field on my object with `component.set('v.myObj.name', 'new name')` **every** `<lightning:input />` in the component will have its value updated to `new name` even if it has a value of `{!v.myObj.type}`.

I understand this component is in beta, but this bug seems like a fundamental flaw that makes the component unusable. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this behavior like setting the `sobjectType` fixed `<force:inputField />`?

Update:
I have created a gist with a reduced test case for both problems: https://gist.github.com/dsharrison/5e686c8e430a8ead77c91f2f4401ca3a

**lightningInputRepro.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

  <!-- public attributes -->
  <aura:attribute name="myObj" type="Account" default="{Name: '', Type: ''}" access="PUBLIC" />

  <!-- body markup -->
  <c:lightningInputReproFields record="{!v.myObj}" />
  <lightning:button label="Update Object" onclick="{!c.updateObj}" />
  <lightning:button label="Update Name" onclick="{!c.updateName}" />

</aura:component>
```

**lightningInputReproController.js**

```
({
  updateObj: function (component, event, helper) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
    var newObj = {
      'Name': 'new name ' + rand,
      'Type': 'new type ' + rand
    };
    component.set('v.myObj', newObj);
  },
  updateName: function (component, event, helper) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
    component.set('v.myObj.Name', 'new name ' + rand);
  }
})
```

**lightningInputReproFields.cmp**

```
<aura:component >

  <!-- public attributes -->
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Account" default="{Name: '', Type: ''}" access="PUBLIC" />

  <!-- body markup -->
  <lightning:input name="name" type="text" label="Name" value="{!v.record.Name}" />
  <lightning:input name="type" type="text" label="Type" value="{!v.record.Type}" />

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right `<ligthning:input/>` treat changes different manner then ui:input Text. The changes in the fields of the object are treated as changes of the object itself.

---

the root cause is that every change on nested field is treated as the change in object itself. If you attach the event change listener on "myObj" or on "record" - you will be able to console.log(event) and see that in case on object update - the old and new value is object, on name update - old and new values are string literals.

---

So, just to unblock you really quick - use these two lines instead of lightning ones

```
  <ui:inputText label="Name" value="{!v.record.Name}" />
  <ui:inputText label="Type" value="{!v.record.Type}" />
```

---

If you really want to make lightning inputs work - here is the workaround 2:
If you move buttons and handler methods in to inner component (lightningInputReproFields) - all works just fine, the updates to object are applied well and update to the name works fine also.

The whole code is below.

------lightningInputRepro.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="myobj" type="Account" default='{"name":"", "type":""}' access="PUBLIC" />    

  <!-- body markup -->
  <c:lightningInputReproFields record="{!v.myobj}"/>

</aura:component>
```

------lightningInputReproFields.cmp

```
<aura:component >
  <!-- public attributes -->
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Account" default='{"name":"", "type":""}' access="PUBLIC" />    
  <lightning:input name="name" type="text" label="Name" value="{!v.record.name}" />
  <lightning:input name="type" type="text" label="Type" value="{!v.record.type}" />

  <lightning:button label="Update Object" onclick="{!c.updateObj}" />
  <lightning:button label="Update Name" onclick="{!c.updateName}" />
</aura:component>
```

------lightningInputReproFieldsController.js

```
({
  updateObj: function (component, event, helper) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
    component.set('v.record.name', 'new name ' + rand);
    component.set('v.record.type', 'new type ' + rand);
  },

  updateName: function (component, event, helper) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
    component.set('v.record.name', 'new name ' + rand);
  }

})
```

Note: this is extremely hard to fine the documentation onlightning:input in the internet. So if you need it - the best way is to go to /auradocs resource in winter17 org and then Reference->Components->lightning->input

---

The third solution would be to retain more control by handling chages manualy with change handlers

```
<aura:attribute name="recordName" type="String" default='{!v.record.name}'  access="PUBLIC" />
<aura:attribute name="recordType" type="String" default='{!v.record.type}'  access="PUBLIC" />

<aura:handler name="change"         value="{!v.record}" action="{!c.recordUpdateHandler}" />

recordUpdateHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.recordName", component.get("v.record").name);
    component.set("v.recordType", component.get("v.record").type);
    console.log(event);
}
```

---

the record update handler can be implemented the way you like it to be and update any objects you want synchronously or with events. So if you want your button handlers be in parent component - send the event from inner component to the wrapping one.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the details. The issue with using `ui:inputText` is that then we must write all validation ourselves (we are actually doing this today). This is the main feature of the `lightning:input` that we were hoping to leverage. As for moving the events to the inner components, this would require a major restructure of our application and would defeat our design pattern of small reusable components. It sounds like we might just be stuck with our own validation using `ui:inputText` until Salesforce fixes these major issues with `lightning:input`.